# How to solve a matrix functional equation containing matrix exponential?

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-equations, functional-equations, queueing-theory

For a given complex value $s$, I wonder how to solve a matrix functional equation for matrix $\hat{G}(s)$ in the following form

$$\hat{G}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{[D_0+D_1\hat{G}(s)-sI]x}dB(x),$$

where $D_0$ and $D_1$ are $2\times2$ matrices with known real values, $I$ is $2\times2$ identity matrix, and $B(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function (CDF). Numerical approximation would be enough. May I know what is the general approach to solve such an equation? Note that the form $e^{A(s)x}$ is matrix exponential.

Some application background if needed: this $\hat{G}(s)$ is the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of the busy period of a 2-state MMPP/G/1, where MMPP stands for Markov Modulated Poisson process. $B(x)$ is the service time distribution. I need to evaluate $\hat{G}(s)$ at some specific $s$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible numeical approach:fix an $s$ and parametrize $G(s)$ as $$G(s) = \begin{bmatrix} a && b \\ c && d\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then find the similarity $S$ transform that diagonalizes $D_0 + D_1 G(s) - sI $ as a function of $a,b,c,d$. This allows you to compute the exponential, $$S^{-1}[\int  e^{\Lambda x}dB(x)]S,$$ with $\Lambda$ the diagonalized matrix
$$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &&  0\\ 0 && \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now you have a closed form for the integral in terms of $a,b,c,d$. This can be compared element by element to $G$, and you have a system of 4 nonlinear equations, which can be plugged into a numerical solver.